# GracenotemusicID.Framework. In that .h file not found error - Xcode 6.4 - ios

Tags: ios, gracenote

When i try to build the App in Xcode, i get GNConfig.h file not found error.
But the file is present.
How to resolve it? 
I have moved the files from another mac.
I have a doubt whether the framework has deprecated.

Comment: First remove GracenotemusicID.Framework reference and clean and build project then after re-add GracenotemusicID.Framework and clean and build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Header path seems to be incorrect. Delete the reference of the framework from project and drag and drop the framework again inside framework folder.

It should resolve the issue

Comment: @mihir.xcode is not able to find the header file. i did what you said. can you how to set the path of framework in xcode in detail.